# Mirantis Fuel: what is nailgun server?

Tags: openstack, nailgun

Sorry for my naive question :(. But i am unable to figure out what is NailGun server and whats its use in Mirantis Fuel?
      When I searched internet, i came across 2 nailgun servers,

```
 1)Nailgun Server helps to run all your Java apps in the same JVM 
 2)Nailgun python library which facilitates easy usage of the Satellite 6 API
```

But I also not clear what Satellite 6 API means!. Could some one help me in knowing what Nailgun is? and how it is used in Mirantis Fuel?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

[Red Hat Satellite 6 (Satellite6)](https://access.redhat.com/products/red-hat-satellite) is an on-premise alternative to trying to download all of your content from the Red Hat content delivery network or managing your subscriptions through the Customer Portal.

[Nailgun](https://github.com/SatelliteQE/nailgun) is a python wrapper utility to easily interact with Red Hat Satellite 6 server APIs.

I am not sure what Nailgun means with respect to Mirantis products.